find and replace regex with multiple lines
so i have this
<desc> description about a game
that is fun and exciting
and things happen</desc>

how do i use regex to find and edit the segment like so
about="description about a game
that is fun and exciting
and things happen"

ive tried a couple different ones <desc>[\s\S\n]+?</desc> and <desc>.*(.*\n)+?.*</desc> and it highlights the section but when trying replacing with about="[\s\S\n]+?" or about="[\s\S\n]+?"it just outputs about="[\s\S\n]+?" and about="[\s\S\n]+?"

Using what?  Are you trying to do this as a find-and-replace in VSCode?

Use a capture group and back reference. Find: <desc>([\s\S]+?)</desc>, replace: about="$1"

yes im using vscode. and i couldnt get ([\s\S]+?) to find anything but ([\s\S\n]+?) did the trick. i forgot about the $1 being the refrence to what that was though so that got it working. Thank you
